# Filter certain months from time series with frequency=365

Tags: time, filter, subset, series

I am working with climate data and have a time series of daily temperature measurements from 1974 to 2012. I want to subset my time series into 2 time series, one of the growing season (1 april - 31 august) and the non-growing season (1 september - 31 march).

My data looks something like this:

[1]  98.9  98.7 100.9 102.4 105.1 106.7 105.9 104.6 103.9 103.8 107.0 108.4 108.0 107.4 110.6 107.3
[17] 106.2 108.7 108.2 106.5 102.3 102.1 107.5 106.5 105.7 103.7 104.8 105.8 105.1 104.6 106.1 106.6
[33] 106.0 103.3 103.1 104.4 102.9 103.0 104.0 109.8 110.5 111.5 107.9 106.1 104.9 105.7 107.1 104.8
[49] 105.7 103.5 101.4 103.1 105.7 105.7 101.7 100.7 102.1 101.4 101.9 101.9 101.4 101.4 101.2 101.2

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to do this depending on what tool you are using. Time-series databases are good for this sort of workflow. With QuestDB for example you can get this as follows:

```
-- Growing season
select * from weather where month(timestamp)>3 and month(timestamp)<9;
```

You can try this exact query on an actual weather dataset [here](http://try.questdb.io:9000) (just copy paste from the above into the editor and click `run`). My dataset has about 30-minute resolution, but this should work the same on your daily dataset.

You can adapt this query for the other season. Then you can download the results as a csv. Lastly, if you want the output to be ordered by timestamp (it already is in my example but perhaps your original data is unordered), you can use `ORDER BY timestamp`.